# Laravel Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'submitform_id' cannot be null in many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I got an error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'submitform_id' cannot be
>   null

I tried to insert `fisherman` array data using `Insomnia/Postman` in `POST` request

### `SubmitForm` model

```php
public function fisherman()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Fisherman::class, 'submitform_fisherman','submitform_id', 'fisherman_id');
}
```

### `Fisherman` model

```php
public function submitForm()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SubmitForm::class,'submitform_fisherman','fisherman_id', 'submitform_id');
    }
```

### `SubmitForm` controller

```php
$sf = new SubmitForm;
$sf->price_per_kg = $request->price_per_kg;
$sf->fisherman()->sync($request->fisherman, false);
if ($sf->save()) {
  return $this->responseSuccess("OK");
}
```

I want to insert many `fisherman_id` with the same `submitform_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to save the `fisherman` model first. See below:

```php
$sf = new SubmitForm;
$sf->price_per_kg = $request->price_per_kg;

if ($sf->save()) {
    $sf->fisherman()->sync($request->fisherman, false);

    return $this->responseSuccess("OK");
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!